# JMS - setting messages in session

Tags: jms

While sending email messages through JMS, is it necessary to always put your messages in a session (while sending and receving both). What if I simply save the message xml in a string variable and pass it to send().

Thanks
Saakshi

Comment: Well, what happens if you try that?

Comment: I am able to send emails the same way. However since i've always seen the code with messages stored in session variables, so was wondering why was that done. 

In my code I dont want to receive any emails but just send them across to users. Therefore I dont see any need to stote the message in session .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it...its not necessary to put your message in the session...even works without that....